# Integer in parentheses not compiling - Why?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, int

I'm initializing two integers `a` and `b`.

It compiles fine for `a` but there is an error for `b`.

```
public class Main_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = -2147483648; //Working fine
        int b = -(2147483648); //Compilation error: The literal 2147483648 of type int is out of range 
    }
}
```

Please help me understand this behavior ?

Comment: The compiler error kind of gives a hint on this one, doesn't it?

Comment: No its not a hint its a error...:)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The reason is that the `int` datatype has valid values in the range `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`.

When you wrap `2147483648` inside parentheses, it becomes an expression that will be evaluated as an `int`. However, `2147483648` is too big to fit in an `int` (too big by one).

The problem does not happen for `-2147483648` because it is a valid `int` value.

Relevant parts of the JLS:

- adding parentheses creates a "Parenthesized Expressions" ([section 15.8.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5))
- an integer literal, such as `2147483648`, is treated as an `int` by default ([section 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1))

  > An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` (§4.2.1).

Comment: If the expression becomes int . Then why the declared int is working fine.

Comment: @ShowStopper Look at it this way: `-2147483648` is valid, it is the min value. However, writing `-(2147483648)`, there is a need to first evaluate `2147483648` as an `int` (because of the parentheses), but this is too big by 1.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki so what i understand is brackets are part of integer and will account to increase in integer range

Comment: Think of it as `int c = 2147483648;` followed by `int b = -c;`, which is effectively what including the parentheses is doing.

Comment: @ShowStopper Parentheses are not part of the integer. The parentheses force the order of operations to first evaluate the positive integer inside the parentheses then the `-` on the outside. The positive integer inside the parentheses is 1 larger than the bounds of `int`

Answer (score 11):

int values go from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. So `-(2147483648)` is OutOfRange because the value inside the brackets is evaluated as an `int`. The max value you can put into the brackets is

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE //Which is equals to 2147483647
```

Answer (score 7):

The compilation error is pretty clear: you are using the `int` literal which is out of range. If you really want to do it, you may use `long` literal:

```
int b = (int) -(2147483648L);
```

Or `double` literal:

```
int b = (int) -(2147483648.0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Max value of int is `2147483647` and min value of int is `-2147483648`. But when you put `2147483648` into braces it initially consider as `+2147483648` and it is not in valid for int rage.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to visualize this is to look at `(int) -(2147483648)` as:

```
(int) -1 * (2147483648)
```

When this is evaluated by the compiler, it says, I have to first convert the number in the parenthesis to an integer, then multiply that by negative 1. It then proceeds to do a range check on the number and discovers that it is larger than what can fit in an integer (2147483648), which is the compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

`int` data type is a `32-bit signed two's complement integer`.

Minimum value is `- 2,147,483,648.(-2^31)`

Maximum value is `2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1)`